# PyGTK Binaries for Mac

Tags: macos, pygtk, glade, binaries

I'm trying to find the Mac OS X binaries for PyGTK 2.24, PyCairo, and PyGObjects, as well as for Glade 2.8.0.

Where can I download these?

Comment: I assume you mean Glade 3.8.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think precompiled binaries are available.

You can install via [macports](http://www.macports.org/) or [fink](http://www.finkproject.org/): PyGTK from these package repositories use X11.

There's a native port of GTK at [gtk-osx.sourceforge](http://gtk-osx.sourceforge.net/). I don't know how mature it is, because I haven't followed it for the last few years. In this case I'm afraid you need to build it yourself.

Comment: When I install via macports, "import gtk" gives ImportError: No module named gtk.  Any idea why?

Answer (score 3):

The included versions are one older than what you specified, but the [0install](http://zero-install.sourceforge.net/install-mac.html) project has a very nice Quartz build [installer package](http://afb.users.sourceforge.net/zero-install/PyGTK.pkg).